# How to access localhost from docker to mobile?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to view the apps from mobile devices. I have tried to use the ip address of my laptop but i still cant accessed to the apps from mobile devices. I can run the apps locally in my laptop but not in other devices although they are using the same network WIFI. I have tried to add `ENV HOST 0.0.0.0` which helps to solve connection outside but it still cannot be accessible in my mobile devices. Is there any solution for this ?

Docker File

```
FROM node:16.14.0-alpine3.15 as builder
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --frozen-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=false

RUN yarn generate

RUN rm -rf node_modules &amp;&amp; \
  NODE_ENV=production yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --pure-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=true


# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=builder /app/.output/public /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: python:3.6
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/backend
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        command: bash -c "cd ./backend && pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py migrate && python manage.p>
    frontend:
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        logging:
            driver: "json-file"
            options:
                max-file: "5"
                max-size: 50m
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 3001:80
```

Comment: You are exposing your frontend on the port 3001 of your laptop so in order to access it you need to add the port at the end of the URL on your mobile device.
Alternatively you can just change your docker-compose to expose the frontend on port 80. --> - 80:80

Comment: u mean https://<ipaddress>:80 ?

Comment: it returns a google search on port 80 80

Comment: i can run locally in computer using localhost:3001 but in mobile devices , i try to use ipaddress:3001 since both mobile and computer are connected to the same wifi networks

Comment: I originally meant using http://<ip-address>:3001 since you're not exposing the HTTPS port which is 443 but the HTTP port 80. If both are on the same network and subnet the mobile device should be able to access your application using the exposed host port 3001 as configured in your docker-compose.

Comment: yes but unfortunately i cant work. probably there is something wrong with configuration

Comment: I have the same problem